# Get image name from UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

In one of my project there is a functionality to pick image from Photos. So for that I've used one third party lib named "YangMingShan". The functionality works perfect as per my requirement.

But the problem is that, I want to get the image name picked from the Photos. Whenever I picked single image from photos, it called below method. And it gives me image.

```
func photoPickerViewController(_ picker: YMSPhotoPickerViewController!, didFinishPicking image: UIImage!) {
}
```

Can anyone please help me to get the image name from image ?

Comment: why you want to get the image name?

Comment: Because I need to show image name with its size in tableview listing.

Answer (score 1):

```
  func photoPickerViewController(_ picker: YMSPhotoPickerViewController!, didFinishPickingImages photoAssets: [PHAsset]!) {
        // Remember images you get here is PHAsset array, you need to implement PHImageManager to get UIImage data by yourself
        picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions.init()
            options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
            options.resizeMode = .exact
            options.isSynchronous = true
            
            var imagesWithName:[ImageModel] = []
            for asset: PHAsset in photoAssets {
                print(asset.originalFilename)
                let image = asset.getImage()
                let fileName = asset.originalFilename
                imagesWithName.append(ImageModel(name: fileName, image: image))
            }
            print(imagesWithName)
            // Assign to Array with images
        }
    }
```

the extension of PHAsset to get file name as follows

```
  extension PHAsset {
    var primaryResource: PHAssetResource? {
        let types: Set<PHAssetResourceType>
        
        switch mediaType {
        case .video:
            types = [.video, .fullSizeVideo]
        case .image:
            types = [.photo, .fullSizePhoto]
        case .audio:
            types = [.audio]
        case .unknown:
            types = []
        @unknown default:
            types = []
        }
        
        let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: self)
        let resource = resources.first { types.contains($0.type)}
        
        return resource ?? resources.first
    }
    
    var originalFilename: String {
        guard let result = primaryResource else {
            return "file"
        }
        
        return result.originalFilename
    }
    
    func getImage() -> UIImage {
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        var thumbnail = UIImage()
        option.isSynchronous = true
        manager.requestImage(for: self,
                             targetSize: CGSize(width: self.pixelWidth, height: self.pixelHeight),
                             contentMode: .aspectFit,
                             options: option,
                             resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
            thumbnail = result!
        })
        return thumbnail
    }
}
```

and the model

```
struct ImageModel {
    let name:String
    let image:UIImage
}
```

replace the line 77 in Pod -> YangMingSha -> YMSPhotoPicker -> YMSPhotoPickerViewController.h with

```
- (void)photoPickerViewController:(YMSPhotoPickerViewController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image didFinishPickingAssets:(PHAsset *)photoAssets;
```

then after build it will raise two error for that photoAsset parameter missing in delete function

in YMSPhotoPickerViewController.m replace the error part line 256 with

```
[self.delegate photoPickerViewController:self
                                       didFinishPickingImage:[self yms_orientationNormalizedImage:image] didFinishPickingAssets:asset];
```

and in other error also replace the code with

```
PHAsset *asset = self.currentCollectionItem[@"assets"];
                    [self.delegate photoPickerViewController:self
                                       didFinishPickingImage:[self yms_orientationNormalizedImage:image] didFinishPickingAssets:asset];
```

and the singleImage delegate method now should be like this

```
 func photoPickerViewController(_ picker: YMSPhotoPickerViewController!, didFinishPicking image: UIImage!, didFinishPickingAssets photoAssets: PHAsset!) {
        let asset = photoAssets.originalFilename
        let image = photoAssets.getImage()
        print(asset)
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Actually I cant convert from UIImage to [PHAsset]. Otherwise the rest of the thing is easy.

Comment: why you convert image to phasst ?

Comment: becase When i select image from picker ---- func photoPickerViewController(_ picker: YMSPhotoPickerViewController!, didFinishPicking image: UIImage!)-- This method will call. And in this delegate method, i just received selected image as UIImage. I didn't received "photoAssets" as you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: edit my answer just check it out

Comment: just use  photoPickerViewController(_ picker: YMSPhotoPickerViewController!, didFinishPickingImages photoAssets: [PHAsset]!) delegate method because here you can find image, name and creation date with much more

Comment: Your mentioned method is called when you have to select multiple images. But I just want to select one image at a time. And for selecting only one image ---- func photoPickerViewController(_ picker: YMSPhotoPickerViewController!, didFinishPicking image: UIImage!)--- this method will called. so

Comment: For selecting just 1 image you are using a library? if you are using this framework its the way to get image name from assets. Otherwise you should have to declare your own name with UUID or timestamp.

Comment: Actually in 2 screens I need multiple image selection and in 1 screen I need single image selection. And also need selection from photos as well as capture image from camera. So as per my requirement, this library is perfect for me. 
@Zeeshan Ahmed. Anyway, Thank you for you support and help.

Comment: I have edit this framework and get the phasset if you want to try it I ll send you the changes

Comment: Ohh that would be great help. Please send me the changes or send me the zip link so I'll download.

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: Your changes in the framework works well. @Zeeshan Ahmed Thank you so much for your help. I am upvoting your answer.